# Cocoa touch/Xcode - generating NIB-less graphics context

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My app delegate contains:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  // Override point for customization after app launch    
  window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  if (!window) 
  {
    [self release];
    return;
  }

  window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [window layoutSubviews];
}
```

This does get executed, apparently with no errors.  The window variable is NOT `0` so the test `if (! window)` does not cause the function to return.  However no green-background window appears, just the default color.  And in the appController.m file, code in the viewDidLoad method does execute.  However `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` returns null rather than a real context.

What am I leaving out?

Comment: Sorry I didn't do a better job of formatting the code - my first post here.

Comment: no problem - I've fixed the formatting. For future reference, you need to indent each code line with at least 4 spaces (not tabs). Inline code can be surrounded with backticks (`) to make it monospace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your window is not green because the view you're adding with `[window addSubview:viewController.view];` is opaque and covering the entire window.

As to the other problem, if you're asking for the current graphics context in `viewDidLoad`, I don't think there is guaranteed to be one. You can only draw on `UIViews` by subclassing and overriding their `drawRect:(CGRect)` method. If you want to draw outside these, you'll need to create your own graphics context via something like [`CGBitmapContextCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html), then display the results either by drawing them in a view's `drawRect:` or by finding another control that will take a `CGImage` you've made with the bitmap functions (i.e. `UIImage`).

Comment: Thanks.  I commented out the addSubview and then the screen still turns up with the default color BUT when I stop the simulator, my background color shows just before it all goes off - I changed the color to verify this.  So you are apparently correct but something else is also happening.

Comment: If I have to subclass a UIView to override its drawRect, wouldn't that mean that any UIView directly instantiated would be useless, because it would not have an override drawRect?  Probably I am not getting something - how could a view created in Interface Builder be drawn on?

Comment: Indeed, UIViews that are not subclassed have little to no behaviour - they just draw white squares. You can set UIViews created with Interface Builder to be an instance of whatever UIView subclass you want using the "Class" section of the Identity inspector.