# OS X from Carbon to Cocoa window creation?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, opengl, macos-carbon

**Edit: This question has been answered indirectly in the comments (using GLUT to avoid the need for either) but because its not posted as an answer, I cannot "accept" it although my issue is solved.**

I have a cross platform OpenGL application, written in C++, that (on Mac OS X) uses Carbon for the window creation and message pump (Think...NeHe Lesson 1).  Recent changes to my code utilizing C++11 features has made it incompatible with the GCC that comes bundled with XCode.

All of my attempts to use systems like MacPorts, HomeBrew, etc... have failed for different reasons (Mostly due to my need to compile 32bit for Carbon support).  I was originally going to ask if anyone had a better solution for installing an updated G++ in Mac OS X 10.8.

That seems like a short sighted solution (at some point, I will need to upgrade to Cocoa and 64bit) so my question has evolved to asking what would be the most simple way to have my existing (very large) application utilize Cocoa for this task rather than Carbon?

I have all of the "Carbon Code" in its own separate .cpp/.h file, which has only two functions, one to create an OpenGL window, and one that is a message pump that uses ReceiveNextEvent.

---

**Edit:**
To be clearer, I am looking for the best way to design (more or less) a drop in replacement for my existing Carbon window creation, and message pump functions, but in Cocoa.  I understand that being a different API, using different language concepts, that a simple one to one command replacement will not suffice.  My existing code has a source code file for Mac that has two functions which perform core tasks (with Carbon) that I call, InitWindow, and DoEvents.  These create the window, and cycle through the pending events respectively.  It is my goal to replace this source code file with one that uses Cocoa, exposing the same functions so there is little to no modification of my core code.

What would be the best way to achieve my goal?  I am not familiar with Cocoa and Obj-C is alien to me.

Comment: Don't use carbon.  It's old and deprecated anyways.  You can either use the native NSOpenGLView, or use SDL, though you'll have to do my work with NSOpenGLView, as you'll have to implement a lot of the stuff by yourself.

Comment: I just need a simple "drop in" replacement for my Carbon code in Cocoa.  SDL is overkill for what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing a project from carbon to cocoa is no easy task either as cocoa is no carbon replacement.

Comment: It should not be an insurmountable task, since I only use a couple Carbon commands, and my needs are very minimal.  Essentially "CreateNewWindow", "ReceiveNextEvent" (and whatever misc API is required to interact with these two) in Carbon.  If I were creating a GUI application, or had more than these very simple needs, I could understand it being a difficult task, but this one should be fairly simple.  I am just unfamiliar with Cocoa, and the Obj-C interface, so am unsure how to proceed in this surgery.

Comment: http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-5731.html

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer this looks like a useful link, I will most definitely look into this once I have "window creation" functional.  Unfortunately I am not versed much in Obj-C speak, so the syntax is alien to me, but it is a good resource to check.

Comment: Have you looked at making it through GLUT instead using pure C++?  It sounds like a more efficient way of making it, than using cocoa by learning Objective-C

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer I was not aware that GLUT would allow me to do this on Cocoa.  I have in the past stayed away from extra dependancies, but this might be a viable solution if it indeed allows for what I need.

Comment: GLUT does NOT require cocoa at all.  Thus you won't need to learn cocoa or Objective-C, which sounds like a good option from what you want. Though there might be better options similar to GLUT, which you'll have to find out yourself.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Thank you.  I have gotten my application to work as designed with GLUT without having to resort to using Cocoa or Obj-C.  There are still a few performance issues with using GLUT like this that I still have to research, but it is definitely a viable solution.

Comment: Here's my answer about switching to Cocoa and using the NSOpenGLView-related stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694594/how-can-i-break-away-from-cocoa-and-develop-mac-opengl-applications-in-c-c/10698446#10698446   I believe that is useful for you since your application is in C++

Answer (score 0):

Going to Cocoa 64-bit definitely sounds like a great idea. And I recommend using some of the native UI if you want to make your users happy, too.

The easiest thing to do would be to create an `NSWindow` with an `NSOpenGLView` in it. You can either do that in Interface Builder, or in code. It's probably best to do it by creating a new Cocoa app using Xcode's template (File > New Project > Cocoa App). That will give you a window by default. You can open it in Interface Builder and add an `NSOpenGLView` to it. You can make the view a custom subclass of `NSOpenGLView`, and add your event handling to it. See the docs for [`NSResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information on how Cocoa dispatches events.

Comment: There is no need for any "native UI" since there is no UI to speak of.  I need to know the best way to design a simple "drop in" replacement for my Carbon code.  I have an existing application that is over a hundred thousand lines of code, in C++ which needs a replacement for Carbon (which is only used to create a window, and manage key presses).  Using Xcode or similar tools may provide some template application, but this is not the problem.  I need a drop in replacement for what I already have and a way to link it to my existing C++ code.

Comment: What part of what I suggested don't you understand? It can do what you want. `NSOpenGLView` is the way to display OpenGL in a window in a Cocoa app. There is no other way that I know of. Also, if you want to handle events, your view will receive them and can process them. That's how event handling works in Cocoa. There's no other way to receive events that I know of. You don't need to use Xcode. You can use make files, or whatever if that's your preference. But if you want to make it a Cocoa app, using an `NSWindow` with an `NSOpenGLView` is the answer, as several others said above.

Comment: There is no lack of understanding, you suggested multiple things (Create a project with Xcode, use Interface builder, etc...) and none of these things are actual answers to my question, which involves an existing, very large cross platform C++ project that I wish to switch out the few Carbon commands for Cocoa ones.  The recommendation of NSOpenGLView is a good one, but not really what I am asking.  I can see how to make an OpenGL window in Cocoa from NeHe examples.  What I can not see is the best way to shoe horn that into an existing C++ project.

Comment: What I am looking to do, is something as simple as this:

`/* Include Some Stuff*/
main(arg….)
{
/* Init Some Stuff */
CreateMacWindow("Hello World", 800, 600);
/* Run My Code */
}

void CreateMacWindow(……)
{
/* 
Call Cocoa Functions
to create a Mac "window"
*/

/*
Add "OpenGL View" to the window 
*/
}`

This is how my app works in Windows, Linux, Mac (with Carbon), and other OSes, and I am trying to get the same (more or less) with Cocoa, so I do not have to have too much platform specific changes.  If I can manage the above, that is all I need.

Comment: Cocoa doesn't work quite the way you want. You can allocate an `NSWindow` with `NSWindow* myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:::];`. And you can add an `NSOpenGLView` to it using `[myWindow setContentView:myOpenGLView];` And then your custom `NSOpenGLView` subclass can handle the events. You can directly call C++ from Objective-C. The only thing you have to do is name your files with the ".mm" extension instead of ".m" and they'll be "Objective-C++". But to get events, I believe you need to run an NSRunLoop, which is best done by just making an `NSApplication`. It's harder not to.

Comment: @user118321 I think we are on two different pages.  I have no desire to sub class a "view", there are no events that I am trying to get from the view, I just need a canvas that I can render OpenGL to as I normally would in Windows, Linux, or Mac OS X (Carbon).  I understand that I will need a different approach with the "event loop" (all I care about is key presses if that makes any difference), which brings me to the main point of my question, what is the best way I can do this that does not require a large redesign/rewrite of my platform agnostic code.  (its not worth the effort otherwise)

Comment: Wow.. just so you know, latreides, by using GLUT you are doing exactly what he suggested you do but with clunky API in-between.  Hows does GLUT get its window and wrap it in that C interface?  Look above.